# AngularJS Resource Options withCredentials Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I am having an issue with using AngularJS resource to be able to, PUT, POST or DELETE . However GET works just great.

Ultimately I have a .NET Web API that is my server-side I have enabled CORS but I am using Windows Authentication to be able to Authorize the user.

On my app.Config for angular I have added withCredentials:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}
]);
```

Inside my AngularJS Controller I have something this:

```
var ModelGrab = $resource($rootScope.baseurl + 'Staging/GIS/CurrentTransformer/:id', null, { 'delete': { method: 'DELETE' } });
```

Now when I call to GET this function like this:

```
ModelGrab.get({ page: $scope.currentPage, records: $scope.recordsperpage, sort: $scope.sortType, reverse: $scope.sortReverse, search: $scope.search, all: false }).$promise.then(function (model) {
        $rootScope.model = model.List;
        $scope.totalItems = model.Count;
        setTotalPages();
    }, function (errResponse) {
        $scope.showMessage('Error retrieving the model', 'danger');
    });
```

Everything loads just fine. However when I go to call the DELETE function like this:

```
ModelGrab.delete({ 'ID': ID }, function () {
                    $scope.showMessage('Data saved successfully', 'success');
                    GetData();
                }, function (e) {
                    $scope.showMessage('An error occurred while trying to save the data', 'danger');
                });
```

I get an error:

OPTIONS http://localhost:32200/api/Staging/GIS/CurrentTransformer?ID=1 http://localhost:32200/api/Staging/GIS/CurrentTransformer?ID=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:27062' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Now when I look up the Network info to see if it passed the withCredentials on the DELETE action I noticed it did not pass it.

Inside my ASP.NET Startup I have setup for CORS so I should be good to go here to accept it:

```
var policy = new Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core.CorsPolicy();

        policy.Headers.Add("*");
        policy.Methods.Add("*");
        policy.Origins.Add("http://localhost:27062");
        policy.SupportsCredentials = true;

        services.ConfigureCors(x => x.AddPolicy("ADMSCORS", policy));
        services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<ADMSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("Data:ConnectionString").Value));

        services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ADMSServices", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireRole(Configuration.GetSection("Security:Role").Value).Build());
        });
```

Inside my configure on my Startup I have added:

```
app.UseCors("ADMSCORS");
```

Inside my controller I have the following:

```
[Route("api/Staging/GIS/CurrentTransformer")]
[Authorize(Policy = "ADMSServices")]
public class CurrentTransformerController : Controller
{
    [FromServices]
    public ADMSContext _Context { get; set; }
    [HttpGet]
    public ListObject Get(int page, int records, string sort, bool reverse, string search, bool all)
    {
        ListObject model = new ListObject();
        model.List = GetList(page, records, sort, reverse, search, all);

        model.Count = _Context.CurrentTransformers.Count();
        return model;
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var model = _Context.CurrentTransformers.SingleOrDefault(line => line.ID == id);
        if (model != null)
        {
            _Context.CurrentTransformers.Remove(model);
            _Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to be able to figure out why I am getting the error on PUT, POST & DELETE. Why is it not passing the windows authentication with the commands?